# Instantiate Decimal class

Tags: python-3.3

I've found a strange behavior in the decimal module. The "signature" of the class Decimal is:

```
Decimal(value='0', context=None)
```

So, I supposed that I can do something like:`Decimal('3', None)`. But this code raises a TypeError exception in python3.3 but not in python2.7.

In my investigations, I tried debugging with pdb:`pdb.set_trace("Decimal('3', None)")`, but nothing happened! As soon as I type `s` the same exception is raised.

Can someone explain the reasons of these behaviors?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm unable to reproduce this under Python 3.2.3: `import decimal; decimal.Decimal("3", None)` successfully returns `Decimal('3')`.

Comment: [It's a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue15783)

Comment: @SilentGhost: I see in the link that it's a bug in the c accelerator version of the module (whatever this is). This can explain why I get nothing from pdb. But can I specify that I want the pure python version?

Comment: @GTux: it would be a hack. Can't you just check what you're passing to constructor?

Comment: @SilentGhost: that's what i'm doing. I wanted to learn a new trick :)

Comment: @SilentGhost: My apology (+1's to the comments). I did not want to steal the idea. I just did not noticed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm the behaviour for Python 3.3. It somehow detects that you passed the `None` as the context and it does not like it (even though it is documented as the default value).

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('3', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: optional argument must be a context
>>> decimal.Decimal('3')
Decimal('3')
```

**Update:** But it works with 3.2.3

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:12:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('3', None)
Decimal('3')
>>>
```

**Update: The reason can be found in the doc...**

[What’s New In Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#decimal) says:

> decimal
>
> issue 7652 - integrate fast native decimal arithmetic.
>       C-module and libmpdec written by Stefan Krah.

When comparing the `decimal.py` files, they may look the same at first, but the Python 3.3 version contains the following code almost at the end:

```
try:
    import _decimal
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    s1 = set(dir())
    s2 = set(dir(_decimal))
    for name in s1 - s2:
        del globals()[name]
    del s1, s2, name
    from _decimal import *
```

... while the older Python 3.2 does not. It says that if the binary `_decimal` implementation could be imported, the older implementation from `decimal.py` is ignored. And the binary module cannot be debugged using the Python-code debugger.

The question is whether the observed behaviour should not be considered a bug.

Comment: like I said, I just want to understand this behavior, and why I can't see the code execution with pdb. In my code, I use an ugly workaround (I test `context` and call the appropriate form).

Comment: thanks, now I understand. About your question, apparently the bug is already openned, see SilentGhost comment.

Comment: @GTux: The hack mentioned by Silent Ghost could be to comment out the `try` block mentioned in the answer. But in the case, I recommend to rename it and put it to your script directory -- say `mydecimal.py`.

Comment: Now that I know why it's happening, I can sleep peacefully, continue to use my old hack (test `context` before instantiating), and wait for the bug to be fixed.

Comment: @GTux: Yes. And do not forget to add a comment why you did it. (You know, Zaphod Beeblebrox forgot to do that... :)

Comment: Actually, I didn't think to do so. So thank you again, good advice.