# Merging PDF files with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I am writing a small script that needs to merge many one-page pdf files. I want the script to run with Python3 and to have as few dependencies as possible.

For the PDF merging part, I tried using [PyPdf](http://knowah.github.com/PyPDF2/). However, the Python 3 support seems to be buggy; It can't handle inkscape generated PDF files (which I need). I have the current git version of PyPdf installed, and the following test script doesn't work:

```
import PyPDF2

output_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

with open("testI.pdf", "rb") as input:
    input_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(input)
    output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(0))

with open("test.pdf", "wb") as output:
    output_pdf.write(output)
```

It throws the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    output.addPage(input.getPage(0))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 420, in getPage
    self._flatten()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 574, in _flatten
    self._flatten(page.getObject(), inherit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 165, in getObject
    return self.pdf.getObject(self).getObject()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 616, in getObject
    retval = readObject(self.stream, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 66, in readObject
    return DictionaryObject.readFromStream(stream, pdf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 526, in readFromStream
    value = readObject(stream, pdf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 57, in readObject
    return ArrayObject.readFromStream(stream, pdf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 152, in readFromStream
    obj = readObject(stream, pdf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 86, in readObject
    return NumberObject.readFromStream(stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 231, in readFromStream
    return FloatObject(name.decode("ascii"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyPdf/generic.py", line 207, in __new__
    return decimal.Decimal.__new__(cls, str(value), context)
TypeError: optional argument must be a context
```

The same script, however, works flawlessly with Python 2.7.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it a bug in the library? Can I work around it without touching the PyPDF library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the answer. The `decimal.Decimal` module in Python3.3 shows some weird behaviour. This is the corresponding StackOverflow question: [Instantiate Decimal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194384/instantiate-decimal-class) I added some workaround to the PyPDF2 library and submitted a pull request.

Comment: Did it go through yet? I am suffering from the same problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I hit the wrong link. This is the correct (but still pending, god knows why) pull request to fix the bug: [click](https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2/pull/4). It's [this](https://github.com/cedeon/PyPDF2) repo.

Comment: Btw, since I have PyPDF2 installed, is there a way to just copy and paste some files?

Comment: This is the commit that fixes the error: [click](https://github.com/cedeon/PyPDF2/commit/c1fd166d8f9c65b40bcdc85ee5be22ca471b90bf) So just copy the green line and add it to the proper place in your file system. (Probably `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py:213`

Comment: Thank you so much! Even though I couldn't get the general thing to work for merging, I wrote a function that avoids the "PdfMerger".

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure you are aware of already existing tools that do exactly this:

- [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit)
- [PDFjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) (my favourite, requires LaTeX though)
- Directly with [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com):
  `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=finished.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf`

Comment: hi, thank you. But I find that PyPDF is a nice library and would like to use it. But thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you're not re-inventing the wheel when you don't actually mean to ;-)