# Inherit class Decimal, and add another input argument in the constructor

Tags: python, inheritance, decimal

A minimal example to reproduce my problem:

```
from decimal import Decimal

class MyDecimal(Decimal):
    def __init__(self, value, dummy):
        super().__init__(value)
        print(dummy)

x = MyDecimal(5, 'test')
```

Throws:

```
TypeError: optional argument must be a context
```

A similar issue is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13194384/16004728), but the answer suggests that this is a bug which was fixed on Python 3.3, and I'm using Python 3.9.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here, or how else I can inherit class `Decimal` while using a different constructor prototype in my class (i.e., additional input arguments before and after the input argument passed to the base class upon construction)?

Comment: Decimals are immutable, I'd guess this check is being done in `__new__` not `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decimal.Decimal` uses [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) instead of `__init__`, because Decimal instances are immutable, and initializing in `__init__` would be a mutative operation. You need to implement `__new__` yourself:

```
import decimal

class MyDecimal(decimal.Decimal):
    def __new__(cls, value, dummy):
        print(dummy)
        return super().__new__(cls, value)
```

Comment: 1. Thank you very much for your answer!. 2. How exactly are they immutable when I can do something like `x += 5` (or am I not interpreting 'immutable' correctly)? 3. Do I need to implement `__new__` in addition to `__init__` or instead of `__init__`?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: `x += 5` will create a new Decimal. It will not mutate the original. As for `__init__`, you do not need to implement it. Just `__new__`. Implementing both in the same class is usually a mistake, and will lead to weird initialization order issues in subclasses.

Comment: OK, something fundamental is missing in your answer, probably due to the very simple MVP that I posted. I don't really have a 'dummy' input argument that I print. I have an input argument which I store into `self`. How exactly can I achieve that when there IS no `self`?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: What do you mean by "store into `self`"? If you mean assigning it to an attribute, then just assign it to an attribute of the new object - the one created by `super().__new__`. That'll work fine. The parts of your object structure that are inherited from `decimal.Decimal` are immutable, but attributes you add in the subclass can be assigned normally.

Comment: I mean, instead of `print(dummy)`, I need to do `self.dummy = dummy`.

Comment: Then just set a `dummy` attribute on the new object. `retval = super().__new__(cls, value); retval.dummy = dummy; return retval`.